# Route [file-upload] not defined laravel-8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to set a route over their but Route [file-upload] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp - 1.0.2\resources\views\navigation-menu.blade.php) error is showing
This is resources\views\navigation-menu.blade.php

```
<x-jet-dropdown-link href="{{ route('file-upload') }}">
{{ __('Highlights') }}
</x-jet-dropdown-link>
```

This is my file location views/file-upload
[image]

Comment: did you define a route and name it `file-upload`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing this

```
<x-jet-dropdown-link href="/file-upload">
{{ __('Highlights') }}
</x-jet-dropdown-link>
```